# c++ member variable not being changed outside of function

Tags: c++

The attached code seems to work as desired, but when it is in separate files main.cpp, Set.h, Set.cpp filled is not decrementing outside of the remove function. I really don't understand what is going on here. Or why it would make any difference that its all in one file.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef int value_type;

class Set {
private:
value_type *dataArray, size, filled;
public:

Set() {
    size = 50;
    dataArray = new value_type[size];
    filled = 0;
}

bool Set::isFull() const {
    return (filled == size) ? true : false; // if filled is equal to size then full.
}

bool Set::remove(const value_type& item) {

    for (int index = 0; index < filled; index++) {
        if (index != (filled - 1) && dataArray[index] == item) {
            dataArray[index] = dataArray[filled - 1];
            --filled;
            return true;

        } else {
            --filled;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void Set::insert(const value_type& newItem) {

    if (!isFull()) {
        dataArray[filled] = newItem;

        filled++; // increment filled to account for new entry.

    }
}

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Set& obj) {
    out << "\nfilled: " << obj.filled << endl;
    out << "{";

    for (int index = 0; index < obj.filled; index++) {
        out << obj.dataArray[index];
        if (index != (obj.filled - 1))
            cout << ",";

    }
    out << "}";
    return out;
}
};
Set firstSet;

void pauseNwait() {
cout << "<--Enter to Continue-->";
cin.ignore();
cin.get();
}

int main() {

int choice = -1;
value_type input;

while (choice != 0) {
    cout << "       Set Manager" << endl
            << " (1) Add item to Set 1" << endl
            << " (2) Remove item from Set 1" << endl
            << " (0) Exit" << endl
            << "-----------------------------------------" << endl
            << "Choose: ";
    cin.clear();

    if (cin >> choice) {
        switch (choice) {
            case 0:
                // Exit.
                break;
            case 1:
                cout << "Enter int to add to list: ";
                cin >> input;
                firstSet.insert(input);
                cout << "First Set: " << firstSet << endl;
                pauseNwait();
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << firstSet << endl;
                cout << "Enter item to remove from list: ";
                cin >> input;
                firstSet.remove(input);
                cout << "First Set: " << firstSet << endl;
                pauseNwait();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } else {
        cin.clear(); // clear cin to avoid invalid menu input errors.
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem Thanks to the people pressuring me to make a smaller version in one file. In the original program I had multiple objects to manipulate, so I had made a function in the main.cpp which would work on the different objects that were supplied in the function paramater. Doing this I was passing a copy of the object to the helper function rather then a reference. The reason the insert function was working fine is because I had passed as a reference. Thank you for all your help, and if I learned anything from this experience, it is that I should provide minimized fully compilable code, this in future may prevent me from having to seek help.

Answer (score 1):

If **dataArray** is a member of the class, what you're seeing could be a side effect of assigning a value out side of the array's bounds.

What will happen is that the value will be set onto an adjacent class member, you won't get any exception because the memory does belong to your program (it's still inside the class).

The scenario:

The loop goes through the array, doesn't find anything.
Now **index** is out of bounds.
You check if the item in that position equals **item**.
It might be equal to item.
then you copy to that place the "last" item in the array.

Comment: that doesnt explain why essentially an unsigned integer wont decrement.

Comment: Have you checked the code that prints the message? you should debug it and see the values yourself with the debugger

Comment: @YochaiTimmer I have checked all that code, and have added outputs in many places to follow changes in filled, for some reason only in that function the value of filled is not being changed outside of  it.

Comment: @cmac147 You need to use filled-- instead of --filled .... See the difference between post and pre increments..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators

Comment: @YochaiTimmer I have tried that, even tried setting filled = 1 and no change outside of the function.